# How do I get x360ce to work in Wine on OS X?

Tags: wine

I am having trouble getting x360ce to work with Wine and cooperate with my Steam game, specifically *Rivals of Aether.* I purchased a Mayflash GameCube Controller Adapter for Wii U & PC USB to be able to use my original GameCube controller on my Macbook Pro 13" retina display laptop. I have used Parallels and managed to get Steam and x360ce to work in that, but I feel that having the the entire VM running to play this one game is unnecessary, and also feel that using Wine would be a simpler and lighter way to play the game.

I have searched Google and Reddit for answers, but they have mostly been answers for Windows, Linux or Abuntu users.

So far I have referenced these for information:

- https://askubuntu.com/posts/399662/revisions
- https://www.reddit.com/r/RivalsOfAether/comments/3mlsv8/guide_getting_roa_working_on_os_x/

For the first one, I can't get past step 7 because I am not entirely sure of how to run the *x360ce.exe*...

I'm new to the Macintosh platform and need a lot of help  as you can see lol. If anyone could guide me towards the right direction or share some better suggestion for an application that will be able to read my GameCube Controller through wine, it would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you could click on package contents on the wrapper you have now made and click wine, then go to install software, and etc. to run x360ce.exe. You then could have the file moved to the right location mentioned in the x360ce guide. Haven't attempted this yet though, but if this doesn't work out, you could always button map using enjoyable, the second guide has explains how to do that. Good luck!